# Get td element instead of its content

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table

This piece of code is taken from [here](https://neil.fraser.name/software/tablesort/tablesort.js)

```
// Fetch the table's data and store it in a dictionary (assoc array).
if (!table.tBodies.length) { return; }// No data in table.
var tablebody = table.tBodies[0];
var cellDictionary = [];

for (var y = 0, row; row = tablebody.rows[y]; y++)
{
    var cell;

    if (row.cells.length)
    {
        cell = row.cells[column];
    }
    else
    { // Dodge Safari 1.0.3 bug
        cell = row.childNodes[column];
    }

    cellDictionary[y] = [TableSort.dom2txt_(cell), row];
}
```

As the comment line says, it fetches the cell content and then sort it. What I want it to do is to fetch the element (is that what you call it?) value instead, like

```
<td actual_value="0">1/1/1970</td>
```

In that above td, it will fetch the value "0" instead of "1/1/1970" to sort. Is that doable?

Comment: So you want the attribute name, not its value?

Comment: I want the value of attribute "actual_value"

Comment: What exactly `TableSort.dom2txt_()` is doing?

Comment: if you don't mind, could you check the .js i linked in the first post? I don't exactly know how to explain what it does

Answer (score 3):

```
.getAttribute("actual_value");
```

Or with jQuery

```
.attr("actual_value");
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Here's the jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/zz4mugen/ look at js line 130

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery you can use

```
.attr('actual_value')
```